# What's the word for... [driving-related]

Tags: vocabulary

The question is too long for me to use it as the title.

Anyhow, what's the word for when someone on the road accelerates and goes in front of you because you're driving too slowly? I need an AmE term.

In French, it would be *dépasser quelqu'un*.

Comment: It's called _overtaking_.

Comment: In (British) English, there is no special term for that, nor anything like it..

"Overtaking" or "passing" or "cutting off/up…" describe manoeuvres but have nothing to do with the reasons for them.

"Road rage" describes a reaction to any number of circumstances, but has nothing to do with any specific outcome thereof.

Answer (score 1):

If they do it in an obnoxious or dangerous manner, you say "they cut me off".

> 2. To abruptly move in front of another driver,

[SOURCE](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Cut+Me+Off)

Comment: In British English, I think "cut me up" is more common.

Comment: Absolutely, "Cut me up" is common. "Cut me off" extremely rare, at best.

Comment: In American English, it's exactly the opposite! Living in California, I hear "cut me off" all the time but have never heard "cut me up" used in this context. Honestly I'd do a double take if I did hear it; it sounds like the person cutting in front of you is a serial killer chopping you up! But such is the nature of idiom...

Answer (score 0):

In English, it is quite similar. It would be *to pass someone*.